# SQL SUM() conditions questions

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+------+--------+----------+
| ID | Code | OpType | Quantity |
+----+------+--------+----------+
|  0 | A    | IN     |        7 |
|  1 | B    | IN     |        8 |
|  2 | A    | OUT    |        2 |
|  3 | B    | IN     |        7 |
|  4 | B    | OUT    |       12 |
+----+------+--------+----------+
```

I want the SUM(Quantity) depending on the OpType. When OpType is OUT, the Quantity field should be multiplied with -1.

The result of the query should be:

```
Code   IN   OUT   Final
A      7    2     5
B      15   12    3
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT(SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Table WHERE OpType = 'IN') AS[IN], (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Table WHERE OpType = 'OUT') AS[OUT], (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Table WHERE OpType = 'IN') - (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Table WHERE OpType = 'OUT') AS[Final]
FROM Table
GROUP BY Code
```

Comment: Formatting needs some work! :)

Comment: @milo2011 In the description of your problem you wrote " When OpType is OUT, the Quantity field should be multiplied with -1." But, in the desired output the values in the OUT column are not negative.  Is that just an oversight?

Comment: No, Adam, the values are positive. Would it be easier if they were negative, when OpType is OUT?

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference whether the values are negative. It wasn't clear to me that the Quantity for the OUT values should only be made negative when determining the Final column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has `PIVOT` functionality.

```
SELECT  [Code], [IN], [OUT], [IN] - [OUT] AS [Final]
FROM
        (
            SELECT  [Code], OpType, SUM(Quantity) Quantity
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY [Code], OpType
        ) org
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(Quantity)
            FOR OpType IN ([IN],[OUT])
        ) pvt
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63460/1)
- [TSQL PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦════╦═════╦═══════╗
║ CODE ║ IN ║ OUT ║ FINAL ║
╠══════╬════╬═════╬═══════╣
║ A    ║  7 ║   2 ║     5 ║
║ B    ║ 15 ║  12 ║     3 ║
╚══════╩════╩═════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Thanks, JW! Wow! This looks complicated. Isn't there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @JW웃 dude! Your second suggested query in the comments is the same as my answer. I guess great minds think alike :)

Comment: There is also a PurchaseDate column, and I would like to get the IN, OUT, FINAL SUMs between two dates and a SUM (let's call it InitialSum) before the lower date interval. See here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce6ed/2

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement inside the SUM for each column so that you only sum the desired values (i.e. for the IN column only SUM up the quantities with OpType='IN' and for the OUT column only SUM up the quantities with OpType='OUT')

```
SELECT Code, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN OpType = 'IN' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as [IN],
    SUM(CASE WHEN OpType = 'OUT' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as [OUT],
    SUM(CASE WHEN OpType = 'OUT' THEN -1 * Quantity ELSE Quantity END) as [FINAL]
FROM Table
GROUP BY Code
```

UPDATE: In a comment to JW 웃's answer, you asked about getting the IN, OUT and FINAL sums between two dates. Below is an updated query which will do that.

```
DECLARE @InitialSumDate DATETIME = '4/22/2013', @EndDate DATETIME = '4/23/2013'
SELECT 
    @InitialSumDate as [InitialSumDate], @EndDate as [EndDate],
    Code, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN PurchaseDate <= @InitialSumDate AND OpType = 'OUT' THEN -1 * Quantity WHEN PurchaseDate <= @InitialSumDate AND OpType = 'IN' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as [InitialSum],
    SUM(CASE WHEN PurchaseDate >  @InitialSumDate AND PurchaseDate <= @EndDate AND OpType = 'IN'  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as [IN],
    SUM(CASE WHEN PurchaseDate >  @InitialSumDate AND PurchaseDate <= @EndDate AND OpType = 'OUT' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as [OUT],
    SUM(CASE WHEN OpType = 'OUT' AND PurchaseDate <= @EndDate THEN -1 * Quantity WHEN OpType = 'IN' AND PurchaseDate <= @EndDate THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as [FINAL]
FROM #Table
GROUP BY Code
```

Comment: @milo2011 please upvote for either my answer or JW웃's answer or both if you found them helpful.